# append a character to the end of a char pointer

Tags: c++, c, string

I have a `char* line` from `fgets (line , 255 , pFile)` that I want to add the character "#" to the end of.  How do I do this in c++?

Something like

```
while ( fgets (line , 255 , pFile) != NULL )
{
    line = line + '#'
}
```

Comment: Just use `std::string`. Don't make it hard on yourself (and let people enter more than 255 characters).

Comment: FYI, you do not append anything "to the end of a pointer". What you're trying to do is append something to the string pointed to by the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strcat(line, "#");
```

Of course the correct answer is to use `std::string` instead.

Comment: And make sure you do it with a check that it'll actually fit (or make the array big enough to hold this and the input).